# Eclipse Indigo Remote System Explorer: FTP Connection

Tags: eclipse, ftp, system, explorer

I installed the RSE Plugin to connect via FTP. I added an FTP-Profile and got errors.

I right-clicked my connection, clicked "Connect"...all fine:

> > 220 ProFTPD 1.3.3e Server (ProFTPD) [81.169.178.18]
>
> USER administrator 331 Password required for administrator
>
> PASS ****** 230 User administrator logged in
>
> SYST 215 UNIX Type: L8
>
> TYPE I 200 Type set to I
>
> PWD 257 "/" is the current directory

After clicking Root, "/" i get the following error:

"Operation failed. File system input or output error"

How can i add a FTP-Connection to sync with a remote project via Remote System Explorer?

Thank you!

Comment: No help on the way...the problem resists. I'm using WinSCP as an alternative, but would be much simpler if i could use it all in one application.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Java 7?
Switching back to Java 6 solved this problem for me. Also refer to this post: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/353749/881617/#msg_881617

Answer (score 1):

Switching back to Java 6 if you're running Java 7 should solve the problem.